# Hibernate, projection and eagerly fetching a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "steps")
public class Step {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private long id;
    //more fields
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "result_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Result result;
```

and

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "results")
 public class Result {
     @Id
     @Column(nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
     private long id;
     //more fields
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "result", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private List<Step> steps;
```

Now I need to get all results and their associated steps.
I will want all the steps so an eager fetch seems best, and I know all results will have steps so an inner join will be fine.
I will want to get only some more fields from results, but not all so I can maximize the use of an index, so projection will be needed.

To accomplish this I have tried two methods:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery(
            "select distinct result from Result as result " +
            "inner join result.steps " +
            "where result.monitorId = :id " +
            "and result.completed between :from and :to ");
query.setLong("id", monitorId);
query.setTimestamp("from", from);
query.setTimestamp("to", to);

for (Result result : query.list()) {
    result.getSteps()
    //work work
}
```

Hibernate does a join like I wanted but when I start to iterate over the results, Hibernate logs one more select query per step I'm using.
(I also haven't found a good way for projection if I'm going this route?)

The second approach I have tried seems great so far:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Result.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("completed"), "completed")
            .add(Projections.property("steps"), "steps"));

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someId", someId));
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("completed", from, to));
criteria.setFetchMode("steps", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class));
```

The projections work great as long as I don't include steps. I'm guessing that has to do with it not belonging to the actual database table? When I do try with steps I get

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

on criteria.list();

So my main question is, how do I best do eager fetching of some but not all columns in results + a collection of steps belonging to each result?
Help please? :)